# Comparing estimators of equal risk

Tags: mathematical-statistics, loss-functions, decision-theory, risk, complete-statistics

I'm attending a course in mathematical statistics and it seems the lecturer tacitly assumes that given estimators $T_1,T_2 : \Omega \to \Lambda$ of a parameter $g : \Theta \to \Lambda$, a loss function $L : \Lambda^2 \to [0\,..\infty)$ and its associated risk $R$ if $T_1$ are equivalent $T_2$ in terms of risk, then they are equal $P_\theta$ a.s. for all $\theta \in \Theta$.

By "equivalent" I mean $T_1 \cong T_2$ where:

$$T_1 \cong T_2 \Leftrightarrow R(T_1,\_) = R(T_2,\_) \Leftrightarrow \forall \theta \in \Theta : R(T_1,\theta) =R(T_2,\theta)$$

This does not seem to be true generally though. E.g. if we consider the square loss $L(x,y) = (x-y)^2$ and we let $\Theta = \{0\}$, $\Lambda = \mathbb R$, $P:=P_0$, $g(x) = x$, then surely we can find $\Omega$ with appropriate $\sigma$-algebra and $T_1,T_2$ such that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not equal $P$-a.s. but that have the same $P$-distribution. Then:
$$R(T_1,\theta)= \int f_\theta\,d(P\circ T^{-1}_1) = \int f_\theta\,d(P\circ T^{-1}_2) =R(T_2,\theta)$$
for all $\theta \in \Theta$, where $f_\theta(x) = (x-\theta)^2$.

My question is:

> How contrived is this example? Are there usually good reasons why $T_1 \cong T_2$ iff $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equal $P_\theta$-a.s. $\theta\in \Theta$ or is this a phenomenon that usually persists?

If yes I also wonder about properties shared by estimators $T_1,T_2$ s.t. $T_1\cong T_2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***The statement as reported is wrong:*** A most standard example is provided by the [James-Stein estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator): given $X\sim\mathcal{N}_p(\theta,I_p)$ $(p>2)$, assuming $\theta$ is estimated under the square error loss,$$L(\theta,\delta)=||\theta-\delta||^2$$the estimators$$\delta_0(x)=x\qquad\text{and}\qquad \delta_{2(p-2)}(x)=\left(1-\frac{2(p-2)}{||x||^2}\right) x$$have exactly the same risk:
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta[||\theta-\delta_0(X)||^2]=\mathbb{E}_\theta[||\theta-\delta_{2(p-2)}(X)||^2]=p$$(The proof goes by Stein's technique of the unbiased estimator of the risk and can be found [e.g.] in [my Bayesian Choice book](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw).) Actually, when two estimators share the same risk functions, they are inadmissible under strictly convex losses in that the average of these two estimators is improving the risk:
$$R(\theta,\{\delta_1+\delta_2\}/2) < R(\theta,\delta_1)=R(\theta,\delta_2)$$which is what is happening with the James-Stein estimators:
$$R(\theta,\{\delta_0+\delta_{2(p-2)}\}/2) < R(\theta,\delta_0)=R(\theta,\delta_{2(p-2)})=p$$with$$\frac{\delta_0+\delta_{2(p-2)}}{2}=\delta_{(p-2)}$$

> I presume the confusion stemmed from the concept of [completeness](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/53107/7224),
>   where having a function with constant expectation under all values of
>   the parameter implies that this function is constant. But, for loss
>   functions, the concept does not apply since the loss depends both on
>   the observation (that is complete in a Normal model) and on the
>   parameter.