# Why are complete statistics named "complete"?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, terminology, complete-statistics

I get why sufficient statistics are named "sufficient", but what about "complete" statistics?

I have this definition from [F.J. Samaniego, *Stochastic Modelling and Statistical Mathematics*, 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Stochastic_Modeling_and_Mathematical_Sta/A5-NAgAAQBAJ): a sufficient statistic $T$ is complete if for all function $g$ such that $\mathbb{E}(g(T)) = 0$, we have $g(t) = 0$ for all $t$ in the support set of $T$.

Is this naming related to the Lehmann-Scheffé theorem which states that an unbiased estimator $\hat\theta = g(T)$ is the unique MVUE of $\theta$ if $T$ is sufficient and complete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of completeness of a statistic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53107/meaning-of-completeness-of-a-statistic)

Comment: The question is not the same but [that answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/285503/228676) does answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is no ambiguity or speculation regarding the usage of *completeness*  for the authors didn't resort to any creative nomenclature but rather stuck to the conventional one.

In functional analysis, there is the general concept of *totality*: a subset $M$ in a normed space $X$ is total if and only if $\overline{\operatorname{span}~ M}=X.$ It can be shown that (cf.$\rm[I]$) that if $X$ is complete, then $M$ is total if for any $x\in X, ~~\ x\perp M\implies x=0.$

As noted in this [lecture](https://web.archive.org/web/20220818121933/htttps://math.ou.edu/%7Ecremling/teaching/lecturenotes/stat/ln5.pdf), the same can be seen here:

> This use of the word complete is analogous to calling a set of vectors $ v_1, \ldots, v_n$ complete if they span the whole space, that is, any $v$ can be written as a linear combination $v = \sum a_jv_j$ of these vectors. This is equivalent to the condition that if $w$ is orthogonal to all $v_j$’s, then $w =0.$ To make the connection with the [definition] let’s consider the discrete case. Then completeness means that $g(t)P(T = t;\theta) = 0 $ implies that $g(t) = 0.$ Since the sum may be viewed as the scalar product of the vectors $(g(t_1),g(t_2),\ldots) $and $(p(t_1),p(t_2),...)$, with $p(t) = P(T = t), $ this is the analog of the orthogonality condition just discussed.

For the sake of completeness, Lehmann and Scheffé used the term *complete kernel* in their $1947$ paper to introduce the concept.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications, *Erwin Kreyszig,* John Wiley & Sons., $1978, $ sec. $3.6, $ p. $169.$